# How to Programmatically Add Multiple UIViewControllers to a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

Through the help of good people here, I've learned how to add a `UIViewController` to a `UIScrollView` - the correct way. Problem is, I need to add multiple view controllers. I tried creating an array of UIViewControllers and then using `for...in` loop to add the controllers as child View Controllers, and then pushing their views to the Scroll View. That's not working.

Right now, I'm only seeing one ViewController in my scroll view, the first one...Can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Please see the relevant code from my `viewDidLoad()`and properties that I set up to create the objects in question:

```
    @IBOutlet var contentScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    var dataArray = [PostViewController]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var da = PostItem(text: "test 1", pic: "beans.jpg")
        var vc =  PostViewController(nibName:"PostViewController", bundle:nil)
        vc.text = da!.postText
        vc.image = da!.postImage
        self.dataArray.append(vc)

        da = PostItem(text: "test 2", pic: "coffeeCup.jpg")
        vc =  PostViewController(nibName:"PostViewController", bundle:nil)
        vc.text = da!.postText
        vc.image = da!.postImage
        self.dataArray.append(vc)

        da = PostItem(text: "test 2", pic: "coffeeMill.jpg")
        vc =  PostViewController(nibName:"PostViewController", bundle:nil)
        vc.text = da!.postText
        vc.image = da!.postImage
        self.dataArray.append(vc)

        //...

        for index in 0..<self.dataArray.count{
            self.frame.origin.y = self.contentScrollView.frame.size.height * CGFloat(index)
            self.frame.size = self.contentScrollView.frame.size
            self.contentScrollView.pagingEnabled = false
            let vc = self.dataArray[index]

            self.addChildViewController(vc)
            self.contentScrollView.addSubview(vc.view)

        }

        self.contentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, CGFloat(self.dataArray.count) * self.contentScrollView.frame.height)
}
```

Comment: You need to set the new vc.view.frame.origin.y to something awell. ATM you are adding every vc to the same position which makes it look like only one is added

Comment: Don't you think that setting the positions in viewDidLoad is too early(try setting them in viewWillLayoutSubviews)? Also, did you try to debug the UIScrollView hierarchy(XCode6 has a view inspector for this)? It can be helpful to see if the views were added properly or if they have a wrong position.

Comment: And does this even compile? if self is a UIViewController then self.frame would not work.

Comment: @Arbitur yes, the code compiles fine. And as I said, it does display ONE of the several view controllers.

Comment: @Tiago Maia, I didn't try the view inspector. I'll try that, to see if I can gain some insight.

Comment: OK, after looking at the view inspector, it looks like the y-coordinate where the new view is supposed to draw isn't being updated, so the views are overlapping each other. @TiagoMaia, thank you for your advice. Please post your comment as an answer so I can upvote you. I'll figure out how to update that y-coordinate.

Comment: Yes, @Arbitur, that is exactly what's happening: the views are overlapping each other

Comment: This is not necessary, as my comment don't answer your question.

Comment: @Arbitur, you are correct: the y coordinates for the second and third `PostViewControllers` wasn't set. I had to add the following lines of code: 
`vc.view.frame.size = self.contentScrollView.frame.size` and 
`vc.view.frame.origin.y = self.contentScrollView.frame.size.height * CGFloat(index)`
The first line correctly sizes each `PostViewController` and the second line sets the y-coordinate correctly for each vc.